# Use the wp-admin translations on the front end

Tags: translation, textdomain

Currently I'm working on implementing the user profile form on the front end. Unfortunately the front end core translation file (`wp-content/languages/lang_LANG.po`) doesn't have any of the translated strings displayed on the user profile page. Those translated strings are located in `wp-content/languages/admin-lang_LANG.po` and since the filename starts with "admin", my best guess is that this only is loaded when visiting a wp-admin page (when `is_admin()` returns true).

Thus how do I load the text domain of wp-admin when you're not viewing a wp-admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way around it would probably be to manually call `load_textdomain()` on the corresponding MO file in your theme's `functions.php`.